# Fetch spreadsheet from zipped file in the mail attachment

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a script to fetch and open a zipped attachment so I can copy the spreadsheet to a Google Sheet in my drive.
I was able to use a script that I got from the group to fetch attached excel spreadsheet from my mail, but can't find one that will unzip an attached file then fetch the excel spreadsheet.
Below is the script I'm working on.
Thank you very much in advance to whoever has answer. It will be very much appreciated.

```
function getRawData() {
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject: Contract/Job Report');
var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

var xlsxBlob = attachment; // Is supposes that attachment[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0].deleteRow(1); // There is the data in 1st tab.
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fgqDXNoUNqYHqEdUUCmZj-GAV5mEh7GSvRlZ65Bhw9M")
var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName("RawData");
//sheet.clearContents();
var range = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
range.setValues(data);

Drive.Files.trash(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.

}
```

Comment: How about [Utilities.unzip()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzip(BlobSource))?

Comment: Hi @Cooper I'm new to script or any type of coding, but somehow I was able to make your suggestion it work, thanks a lot.
     var files = Utilities.unzip(attachment)[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current situation and goal as follows.

- In your script, `attachment` of `var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];` is the blob of ZIP file including a XLSX file.
- You want to retrieve the XLSX file from the ZIP file.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, `unzip(blob)` is required to be used. This has already been mentioned in the comment.
- Here, there is an important point. When the ZIP file of the attachment file is retrieved, the mimeType might be `application/x-zip-compressed`. In this case, when `unzip(blob)` is used, an error of `Invalid argument` occurs. So it is required to set the mimeType of `application/zip`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

var xlsxBlob = attachment; // Is supposes that attachment[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
```

To:

```
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

var xlsxBlob;
var mimeType = attachment.getContentType();
if (mimeType.includes("zip")) {
  attachment.setContentType(MimeType.ZIP); // or attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  xlsxBlob = Utilities.unzip(attachment)[0];
} else if (mimeType == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || mimeType == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
  xlsxBlob = attachment;
}
```

- In this modified script, when `attachment` is the zip file, the unzipped file is put to `xlsxBlob`. When `attachment` is XLSX file, `attachment` is put to `xlsxBlob`.

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that `attachment` of `var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];` is the blob of ZIP file including a XLSX file. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [unzip(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzip(BlobSource))
- [getContentType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getcontenttype)
- [setContentType(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypecontenttype)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, the script that I have worked by adding the Utilities.unzip(attachment)[0].
However, looking at your modified script, I can see that the process is much clearer and cleaner.
Thank you very much for your help, very much appreciated.

Comment: @Angelito Saliva Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.